# Why is symfony performing extra queries for joins

Tags: mysql, symfony, many-to-many

i try to join many2many from a database with myisam tables with joins.

I have the tables article, article_category, actor, article_actor (And many more similar many2many relations).

My Setup in

Article:

> > ```
> > class Article{
> > //....
> >
> > /**
> >  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="articles")
> >  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_category")
> >  */
> > protected $categories;
> >
> > /**
> >  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Actor", inversedBy="articles")
> >  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_actor")
> >  */
> > protected $actors;
> >
> > /**
> >  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Cameraman", inversedBy="cameramen")
> >  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_cameraman")
> >  */
> > public function __construct() {
> >   $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
> >   $this->actors = new ArrayCollection();
> > }
> > ```

Category:

> class Category {
>
> ```
> /**   
>  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="categories")
>  **/  
> protected $articles;       
>
> public function __construct() { 
>   $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
> }
> ```

Actor:

> class Actor {
>
> ```
> /**   
>  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="actors")
>  **/  
> protected $articles;
>
> public function __construct() {
>   $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
> }
> ```

In the ArticleRepository i hav a query with joins:

> class ArticleRepository extends EntityRepository {
>   public function findArticleWithJoins($_titleSlug)   {
>
> ```
> $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
>   ->where('a.titleSlug = :titleSlug')
>   ->setParameter('titleSlug', $_titleSlug)
>   ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'c')
>   ->leftJoin('a.actors', 'ac')
>
>
> return $q->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
> ```
>
> } 
>   }

In my controller i fetch the article with the related joins:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$article = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Article')->findArticleWithJoins('theSlug'); 
return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('article' => $article));
```

And finally in the template as soon as i iterate over the joins, there are 3 queries:

```
{% block body %}
  {{article.title}}<br/>
  {{article.categories.0.name}}<br/>
  {% for actor in article.actors %}
    <li>{{ actor.firstName }} {{ actor.lastName }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The first quer is:

```
SELECT 
  a0_.id AS id0,  
  a0_.title AS title15, 
  a0_.orig_title AS orig_title16, 
  a0_.title_slug AS title_slug17, 

FROM 
  article a0_ 
  LEFT JOIN article_category a2_ ON a0_.id = a2_.article_id 
  LEFT JOIN category c1_ ON c1_.id = a2_.category_id 
  LEFT JOIN article_actor a4_ ON a0_.id = a4_.article_id 
  LEFT JOIN actor a3_ ON a3_.id = a4_.actor_id 
WHERE 
  a0_.title_slug = ?
```

The second query:

```
SELECT 
  t0.id AS id1, 
  t0.name AS name2, 
  t0.slug AS slug3, 
FROM 
  category t0 
  INNER JOIN article_category ON t0.id = article_category.category_id 
WHERE 
  article_category.article_id = ?
```

And the third query:

```
SELECT 
  t0.id AS id1, 
  t0.first_name AS first_name2, 
  t0.last_name AS last_name3, 
  t0.name_slug AS name_slug4, 
FROM 
  actor t0 
  INNER JOIN article_actor ON t0.id = article_actor.actor_id 
WHERE 
  article_actor.article_id = ?
```

I wanted to avoid multiple queries by using the joins in the findArticleWithJoins() function.
But the result is the same just queriying for the article and then select the relations later.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add select (`->select('a, c, ac')` to your query:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
  ->select('a, c, ac')
  ->where('a.titleSlug = :titleSlug')
  ->setParameter('titleSlug', $_titleSlug)
  ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'c')
  ->leftJoin('a.actors', 'ac')
```

This will make doctrine to construct object with relations.

Comment: Whow. Thats it. I have been searching for hours. Thanks a lot :)